# Oracle SQL to find incremental bracket based on criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some data like this :

[image]

My requirement is to get the total pay based on user additional working hours.

```
with t as
 (select 1  from_hour,4  to_hour,20 pay from dual union all
  select 5  from_hour,8  to_hour,50 pay from dual union all
  select 10  from_hour,12  to_hour,100 pay from dual)
, input_data
as
(
select 6 user_hours from dual
)
select t.from_hour,t.to_hour,t.pay
  from t
  join input_data i on 1=1 
  ;
```

For example:

- When user worked for 4 hours, we pay 20$ per hour. Total= 4* 20 = 80$
- When user worked for 6 hours, we pay first 4 hours 20$, then for 5th and 6th hour, we pay 50$.
  [image]
- When user worked for 9 hours, for first 4 hours 20$, then for 5th to 8th hour, we pay 50$,
  for 9th hour we pay 100$.

[image]

Any guidance on how to achieve the HOURS_WORKED column calculation and the data set as above will be much helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: You've presented that table that defines the pattern (1-4=20, 5-8=50, 10-12=100), but where's the employee's table with the hours they actually worked? Is this post missing sample input tables and expected output?

Comment: as a sample in my query, i mentioned 6 hours which is user_hours. Hope that would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/ovlq7ZjO

```
with t as
 (select 1  from_hour,4  to_hour,20 pay from dual union all
  select 5  from_hour,8  to_hour,50 pay from dual union all
  select 10  from_hour,12  to_hour,100 pay from dual)
, input_data
as
(
select 6 user_hours from dual
)
select *
  from input_data i
  outer apply(
     select 
        sum((least(t.to_hour,i.user_hours) - (t.from_hour-1) ) * t.pay) as sum_to_pay
     from t
     where i.user_hours>= t.from_hour
  );
```

Or with an explanation:

```
with t as
 (select 1  from_hour,4  to_hour,20 pay from dual union all
  select 5  from_hour,8  to_hour,50 pay from dual union all
  select 10  from_hour,12  to_hour,100 pay from dual)
, input_data
as
(
select 6 user_hours from dual
)
select *
  from input_data i
  outer apply(
     select 
        (least(t.to_hour,i.user_hours) - (t.from_hour-1) ) as hours_to_pay
       ,(least(t.to_hour,i.user_hours) - (t.from_hour-1) ) * t.pay as sum_to_pay
       ,t.*
     from t
     where i.user_hours>= t.from_hour
  )
  ;
```

`hours_to_pay` - is a number of hours, which we get just comparing user_hours with `to_hour`

and using `outer apply` with `sum()` to aggregate results

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your "*total_pay*" column is derived from the "*hours_worked*" column, so we:

- first compute the working hours, using a `CASE` expression with conditions
- then we apply the product between "*hours_worked*" and corresponding "*pay*"

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT  1 from_hour,  4 to_hour,  20 pay FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5 from_hour,  8 to_hour,  50 pay FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  9 from_hour, 12 to_hour, 100 pay FROM dual
), input_data AS (
  SELECT 6 user_hours FROM dual
)
SELECT t.from_hour,
       t.to_hour,
       t.pay,
       CASE WHEN t.to_hour <= i.user_hours THEN 4 
            ELSE i.user_hours - t.from_hour +1 
       END AS num_hours,
       t.pay * CASE WHEN t.to_hour <= i.user_hours THEN 4 
                    ELSE i.user_hours - t.from_hour +1 
               END AS total_pay
FROM       t
INNER JOIN input_data i
        ON t.from_hour <= i.user_hours
```

**Output**:

| FROM_HOUR | TO_HOUR | PAY | NUM_HOURS | TOTAL_PAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 20 | 4 | 80 |
| 5 | 8 | 50 | 2 | 100 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cw2x7MxA).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub-query to find the total pay:

```sql
select i.user_hours,
       ( SELECT SUM( (LEAST(i.user_hours, to_hour) - from_hour + 1) * pay )
         FROM   t
         WHERE  from_hour <= i.user_hours
       ) AS total_pay
from   input_data i;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t (from_hour, to_hour, pay) AS
  select  1,  4,  20 from dual union all
  select  5,  8,  50 from dual union all
  select  9, 12, 100 from dual;

CREATE TABLE input_data (user_hours) AS
  select 6 user_hours from dual;
```

Outputs:

| USER_HOURS | TOTAL_PAY |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 180 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tuw80muV)

Comment: +1 Thanks for the simple and neat query! As I was needed to have the individual records I just accepted @Sayan's answer. But logic looks same for both. Thanks